# How to troubleshoot Digital Ocean server start / terminated loop?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deployment, digital-ocean

This is my first deployment and it’s a React App. Dev mode is good. The app build goes fine, both locally and on Digital Ocean, however when Digital Ocean starts the app it gets caught in a timeout loop and I need some advice for troubleshooting. The logs don’t really show anything useful. I added Procfile with ‘web: npm start’ to fix the “no server file” message in ‘app build’. The Digital Ocean console is blank. Here’s the build log:

```
-01-29 16:30:59] ╭──────────── git repo clone ───────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:30:59] │  › fetching app source code
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:30:59] │ => Selecting branch "main"
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:12] │ => Checking out commit "682fd85f10f753c6d4f256537876c516a2b28cd0"
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13] │  ✔ cloned repo to /workspace
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13] ╰────────────────────────────────────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13] 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13]  › configuring build-time app environment variables:
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13]      NODE_ENV
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13] 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13]  › configuring custom build command to be run at the end of the build:
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13]    │ yarn build
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:13] 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] ╭──────────── buildpack detection ───────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │  › using Ubuntu 22.04 stack
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │ Detected the following buildpacks suitable to build your app:
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │    heroku/nodejs-engine   v1.5.3  
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │    digitalocean/node      v0.3.6  (Node.js)
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │    digitalocean/procfile  v0.0.4  (Procfile)
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │    digitalocean/custom    v0.1.2  (Custom Build Command)
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │ For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │    Node.js  v0.3.6  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] ╭──────────── build caching ───────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:14] │  › checking for cache from a previous build
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:16] │ Layer cache not found
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:16] │ Layer cache not found
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:17] ╰───────────────────────────────────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:17] 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:17] ╭──────────── app build ───────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:17] │ ---> Node.js Buildpack
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:17] │ ---> Installing toolbox
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:17] │ ---> - jq
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:17] │ ---> - yj
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:18] │ ---> Getting Node version
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:18] │ ---> Resolving Node version
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:19] │ ---> Downloading and extracting Node v20.11.0
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:21] │ ---> Parsing package.json
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:22] │ ---> Installing yarn@1.22.21
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:23] │ ---> No file to start server
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:23] │ ---> either use 'docker run' to start container or add index.js or server.js
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:23] │ Project contains yarn.lock, using yarn
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:23] │ Installing node_modules using yarn (from yarn.lock)
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:23] │ Running yarn install
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:23] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:23] │ yarn install v1.22.21
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:23] │ [1/4] Resolving packages...
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:24] │ [2/4] Fetching packages...
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ [3/4] Linking dependencies...
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "@craco/craco > autoprefixer@10.4.17" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.1.0".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "@craco/craco > cosmiconfig-typescript-loader@1.0.9" has unmet peer dependency "@types/node@*".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "@craco/craco > cosmiconfig-typescript-loader@1.0.9" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=3".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "@craco/craco > cosmiconfig-typescript-loader > ts-node@10.9.2" has unmet peer dependency "@types/node@*".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "@craco/craco > cosmiconfig-typescript-loader > ts-node@10.9.2" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.7".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning " > @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning " > eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^8.0.0".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "react-scripts > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>= 2.7".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning " > source-map-loader@4.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.72.1".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning " > webpack-cli@5.1.4" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@5.x.x".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "webpack-cli > @webpack-cli/configtest@2.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@5.x.x".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "webpack-cli > @webpack-cli/info@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@5.x.x".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning "webpack-cli > @webpack-cli/serve@2.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@5.x.x".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:42] │ warning " > workbox-webpack-plugin@5.1.4" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:52] │ [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:53] │ Done in 29.65s.
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:57] │ Running custom build command: yarn build
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:57] │ yarn run v1.22.21
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:57] │ $ react-scripts build
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:31:58] │ Creating an optimized production build...
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ Compiled successfully.
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ File sizes after gzip:
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │   105.75 kB  build/static/js/main.01ee4d83.js
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │   7.71 kB    build/static/css/main.f189f8ae.css
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │   1.77 kB    build/static/js/988.85674054.chunk.js
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ The build folder is ready to be deployed.
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ You may serve it with a static server:
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │   yarn global add serve
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │   serve -s build
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ Find out more about deployment here:
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │   https://cra.link/deployment
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │ Done in 55.90s.
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] ╰───────────────────────────────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] ╭──────────── app upload ───────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:53] │  › uploading app container image to DOCR
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:54] │ Reusing layers from image <registry-uri-0>
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:55] │ Reusing layer 'heroku/nodejs-engine:nodejs'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:32:55] │ Reusing layer 'heroku/nodejs-engine:yarn'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:09] │ Adding 2/2 app layer(s)
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:09] │ Reusing layer 'launcher'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:09] │ Reusing layer 'config'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:09] │ Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:09] │ Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:09] │ Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:09] │ Saving <image-1>...
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:23] │ *** Images (sha256:185cefb33b15a6a943749c84176f740a2081fc48c78e876005d0940c7b5e1350):
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:23] │       <image-2>
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:23] │ Layer cache not found
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:24] │ Adding cache layer 'heroku/nodejs-engine:nodejs'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:26] │ Adding cache layer 'heroku/nodejs-engine:toolbox'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:26] │ Adding cache layer 'heroku/nodejs-engine:yarn'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:30] │ Adding cache layer 'digitalocean/node:node_modules'
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:36] │  ✔ uploaded app image to DOCR
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:36] ╰────────────────────────────────────╼
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:36] 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:36]  ✔  build complete 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:33:36]
```

And the runtime log.

```
yarn run v1.22.21
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:16:26] $ NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 react-scripts start
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:16:32] (node:34) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:16:32] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:16:32] (node:34) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:16:33] Starting the development server...
[benjamin-cleek-website] [2024-01-29 16:16:33] 
[benjamin-cleek-website] [] was terminated
```

I’ve been running in circles and learning a lot about how to troubleshoot. Alas, I’m at the end of the road and can think of nothing else.

This is my first deployment. I've been bouncing things off chatGPT. What I've learned is there's some layer in the build with Digital Ocean. From the build log, I can see Heroku is involved somehow. At this point, I'm flying blind and am not sure how to get more information from either Digital Ocean or Heroku. I started in with doctl thinking I'd be able to see something more on Digital Ocean but that seems like the wrong tool.

I have also verified my packages.json has a start command and uses react-scripts. I don't have any webpack configurations so I think that error is coming from the Digital Ocean / Heroku exchange.

In a last-ditch effort, I deleted everything from the App and only left the shell to see if I could get rid of any component that might cause an issue like this (again, flying blind) but that didn't change anything.

Comment: In the logs it sys, `Starting the development server`. Have you defined `NODE_ENV: production` in the digital ocean's control panel?

Comment: I have yes, and it's also in a .js file in components

Comment: Heroku is not involved. Digital Ocean is just using Heroku buildpacks.